# TCP - MSS option and different payload

Tags: tcp

[image: screenshoot]

This is a tcpdump from servers side.

In line 1 i see MSS=1400.
Why server sent in line 6 a packet of 4230 bytes when client want max 1400?

Comment: Downvoting for unclear title.

Comment: If I had to guess, Large Send Offload enabled on the server network adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MSS of 1400 and timestamping enabled, there will be room for 1388 bytes of payload in each segment.

If segmentation offloading is being used and 3 segments are grouped together, then such three segments will contain 4164 bytes of payload.

If we then add 12 bytes of timestamps, 20 bytes of TCP header, 20 bytes of IPv4 header, and 14 bytes of Ethernet header, we get 66 bytes of headers.

4164 bytes of payload plus 66 bytes of headers equals 4230 bytes.